# Is it safe to remove when not part in this case statement?

Tags: oracle

The below Case Statement is part of an Select Query.

Is it safe to remove when not part in this case statement ?

Can the **when not** part removed ?
Will removing the **when not** , will have any difference ?

```
WHERE
CASE
WHEN o.order_id <> '0' THEN
  CASE
  WHEN (
      a.acc_id IS NULL
      AND
      o.order_status = ‘a’
    )
    THEN
    1
  WHEN NOT (
      a.acc_id IS NULL
      AND
      o.order_status = ‘a’
    )
    THEN
    0
  END
  ELSE CASE
  
  WHEN (
      (
        o.order_id = '0'
      )
      AND
      a.acc_id IS NULL
      AND
      o.order_status = ‘a’
    )
    THEN
    1
  WHEN NOT (
      (
        o.order_id = '0'
      )
      AND
      a.acc_id IS NULL
      AND
      o.order_status = ‘a’
    )
    THEN
    0
  END
END
= 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a case when returning 1 and a when not (same criteria) to return 0. Case when defaults to `null` for scenarios that are not covered. So, if you remove the when not part, then the expression will evaluate to `null` instead of 0 and `null=1` will filter out the records having such values. So, it seems that it will not be harmful to remove the when not part, but it will be less readable. I would use `else 0` instead of the when not:

```
WHERE
CASE
WHEN o.order_id <> '0' THEN
  CASE
  WHEN (
      a.acc_id IS NULL
      AND
      o.order_status = ‘a’
    )
    THEN
    1
    ELSE
    0
  END
  ELSE CASE
  
  WHEN (
      (
        o.order_id = '0'
      )
      AND
      a.acc_id IS NULL
      AND
      o.order_status = ‘a’
    )
    THEN
    1
    ELSE
    0
  END
END
= 1
```

Comment: This is not quite the same logic on the inner `CASE` expressions.

Comment: @MT0 if `order.status` is `null`, then the code in my answer will have a result of 0, whereas initially it would have been evaluated to `null`. It seems to me that the intention was to have a 0 whenever it was not a 1. Yet, we compare our result to 1 at the end and values resulting in `null` or 0 will be filtered out alike.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner `CASE` expression:

```sql
CASE
WHEN (a.acc_id IS NULL AND o.order_status = 'a')
THEN 1
WHEN NOT (a.acc_id IS NULL AND o.order_status = 'a')
THEN 0
END
```

Produces 3 different values `1`, `0` and `NULL`.

- `1` when `a.acc_id IS NULL AND o.order_status = 'a'`
- `0` when `a.acc_id IS NOT NULL OR o.order_status != 'a'`
- `NULL` when `o.order_status IS NULL`

If you replace the second `WHEN` clause with an `ELSE` clause then you will not get the same logic as there will only be 2 values output by the `CASE` expression.

However, in the outer comparison, neither `0 = 1` or `NULL = 1` will match so although you change the logic of the inner `CASE` expression by removing the `WHEN NOT (...)` clause you will not change the overall logic of the statement.

---

You can simplify it all to:

```sql
WHERE (   o.order_id <> '0'
      AND a.acc_id IS NULL
      AND o.order_status = 'a'
      )
OR    (   o.order_id = '0' -- There should be an OR o.order_id IS NULL
                           -- filter here but it is eliminated by the
                           -- inner CASE expression in your code.
      AND a.acc_id IS NULL
      AND o.order_status = 'a'
      )
```

Which simplifies further to:

```sql
WHERE o.order_id IS NOT NULL
AND   a.acc_id IS NULL
AND   o.order_status = 'a'
```

If you want it in a `CASE` expression then:

```sql
WHERE CASE
      WHEN o.order_id IS NOT NULL
      AND  a.acc_id IS NULL
      AND  o.order_status = 'a'
      THEN 1
      END = 1
```

*(but the `CASE` expression seems pointless.)*